# XPATH - Can I retrieve the type of a variable with an XPATH query for eclipse-pmd plugin?

Tags: eclipse, xpath, pmd

I'm currently working on custom rules for the pmd plugin on eclipse.
Is it possible to retrieve, with an XPATH query, the type of a variable?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to test nodes for their type. For instance

```xml
//VariableDeclaratorId[pmd-java:typeIs('java.lang.StringBuilder')]
```

will match variable declarations with the specified type.

I'm not sure what you mean with "retrieve", but you can't manipulate the type as a first class object in XPath (as of PMD 6.34.0). The only facilities available are the provided [XPath functions](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html#java). Of course you have more possibilities in Java.